# Query to get the next identity?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, identity-column

Query to get the next identity? This is possible for table without deleted records:

```
SELECT TOP 1 EMPID + 1 FROM Employee ORDER BY EMPID DESC
```

If there is deleted data, How I will get the next identity ? For example I have a table like this:

```
EMPID    NAME
4001     someName
4002     someName
4003 ----------------------- this is deleted
4004     someName
4005     someName
4006     someName
4007     someName
4008     someName
4009 ----------------------- this is deleted
4010 ----------------------- this is deleted
```

The ouput must be 4011

Comment: Only a a comment but why do you need that?  Why not just perform the insert and retrieve that iden using scope_identity?

Comment: Will be using in my winform application to display the next EmpID

Comment: @Karlx Maybe a stupid question... but why do you want to display the next `EmpID`?

Comment: This is foolish. If you query to get what the next identity might be by the time you eventually do an insert, someone else might have generated a new value (either committed or rolled back), making your guess completely inaccurate. What is the point of showing the ID anyway? Identity values should be transparent surrogates that end users don't need to know or care about. If they do, then commit the insert, and *then* show them what they got, instead of showing them what they might get.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't "recycle" deleted identity values - ***and that's a GOOD thing!***

Comment: In my application a user will insert a book. For example someBook will be insert with 3 copies. Table1.BookID = 1, Table1.Copy = 3, Then in another table those 3 books will have their primary key so it will be Table2.AccessionID = 1,2,3 Table2.BookID = 1, 1, 1.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels, and the accepted answer is not going to do you any favors when you actually test this with multiple users. :-(

Comment: Then what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Perform the insert first, and *then* show it on your form. Why does your user need to know what ID value they *will* get, before you've assigned it to them? How does this help them if it's wrong?

Comment: See my first comment!  Perform the insert and THEN retrieve the actual iden value used.

Comment: I think the query above is good enough because the user will not be allowed to delete records, instead a Column something like Status will be updated with value `Deleted`

Comment: and if a different user inserts a record between the time your user does, then your data becomes mangled

Comment: @Karlx you're entirely missing the point. Simulate two users of your app by opening two management studio windows. In each one run your `IDENT_CURRENT` query and output the results. Now, insert into the table in one window, and then insert into the other, in both cases check `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. It is 100% impossible for both of them to match the `IDENT_CURRENT` output, but you showed both users that ID on the form. Note that in neither session did you delete anything.

Answer (score 11):

The only way for you to reliably show an `IDENTITY` value on your application's form is to ***INSERT IT FIRST***. `IDENT_CURRENT` might seem to help you when you're the only person testing it, but I can assure you this will fall apart quite quickly once multiple users are using your application. It is very easy to prove, too. Create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.whatever(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), blat CHAR(1));
```

Now, in two separate Management Studio windows, first run this code, which simulates what you'd be showing on the form, if you follow the accepted answer and what you said "works":

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.whatever');
```

Note the output (both should be `1`). This is correct. **SO FAR**.

Now, in one window, run this:

```
INSERT dbo.whatever(blat) SELECT 'x';
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

The output should be `1` (which, again, is correct **SO FAR**).

Now, in the other window, run the same thing, but change `x` to `y`. This output is now `2`. **UH-OH**. This does not match what you showed this user on their form. You can also validate that by seeing there are two rows in the table, with `1` and `2` as the `IDENTITY` values:

```
SELECT ID, blat FROM dbo.whatever;
```

The right way to do this, and the only way to do it, is to insert a row, retrieve the value, and ***then*** show it on the form. If you need to show them some surrogate value beforehand (no idea why you would need to do this, or why your end users need to know this value no matter when you retrieve it - why do users care what the ID is?), then create a separate table and generate your `IDENTITY` values there.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.dummy_table(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY);
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.real_table(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, ...other columns...);
GO
```

Now, when you want to show the "next" ID on the form, you can do so using the following:

```
INSERT dbo.dummy_table DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Then when the user fills out the rest of the information, you can insert into `dbo.real_table` and include the `ID` column in the insert list, using the value you retrieved from `dbo.dummy_table`. Note that this will still end up with gaps in the event that a user saw an ID and didn't click save, but that ID is now meaningless as it never made it into the real table - and there is no possibility for anyone else to have seen it (unlike what can happen with `IDENT_CURRENT`, `MAX+1` and other ill-conceived "check the value first" techniques).

If your actual goal is to insert three copies of the book into another table, the solution is quite simple, and still requires that you insert the book first. Let's assume you have parameters to represent the name of the book and the number of copies (as well as other parameters I'm sure):

```
DECLARE @Copies INT, @name NVARCHAR(32);

SELECT @Copies = 3, @name = N'Moby Dick';
```

Now, we can insert into the `dbo.Books` table, and use the output to insert multiple rows into the other table (`dbo.Accession`?). No need to blindly guess at the "next" value of `BookID` first.

```
DECLARE @BookID INT;

INSERT dbo.Books(name, copies, whatever...) SELECT N'Moby Dick', 3, ...;

SELECT @BookID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT dbo.Accession(AccessionID, BookID)
  SELECT rn, @BookID
  FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP (@Copies) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
    FROM sys.columns ORDER BY [object_id]
  ) AS y;
```

This uses a trick to generate multiple rows from catalog views, but you can also use a built-in `Numbers` table, if you have one, for improved efficiency (and less restrictive permissions).

Comment: No. Those ID will not be shown. It will only stored in an int.

Comment: Yes, but you said it's not good to do that, that's why I change my mind. My problem is with this. In my application a user will insert a book. For example someBook will be insert with 3 copies. Table1.BookID = 1, Table1.Copy = 3, Then in another table those 3 books will have their primary key so it will be Table2.AccessionID = 1,2,3 Table2.BookID = 1, 1, 1.

Comment: @Karlx please start a new question that accurately describes your actual problem. This question seems to have little or nothing to do with this AccessionID problem.'

Comment: @Karlx my answer doesn't need to change but the reason I suggested a different question is because now your question actually has nothing to do with the title of your question, and multiple people have already answered your original question before the edit. It's not fair to completely change your question after any attention has been paid to it. Before you do ***anything else***, please read this thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: Sorry. I will ask another question. But I cannot think of a title. :)

Comment: Well, what does your actual business requirement state? Start there. In this question you started at "how do I technically do what I think the right approach should be to do `x`, which is get the next identity  value before I insert it, and copy that into another table `n` times." What is `x`?

Comment: @Karlx no, `x` is not `the book`. `x` is what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195528/right-approach-to-insert-in-table-then-copy-it-to-another-table

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SQL SERVER – @@IDENTITY vs SCOPE_IDENTITY() vs IDENT_CURRENT – Retrieve Last Inserted Identity of Record](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Please do note the differences, as stqated below.

I would recomend you look at using IDENT_CURRENT.

[IDENT_CURRENT (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx)

> Returns the last identity value generated for a specified table or
>   view. The last identity value generated can be for any session and any
>   scope.

[SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger,
>   function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if
>   they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

[@@IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

> After an INSERT, SELECT INTO, or bulk copy statement is completed,
>   @@IDENTITY contains the last identity value that is generated by the
>   statement. If the statement did not affect any tables with identity
>   columns, @@IDENTITY returns NULL. If multiple rows are inserted,
>   generating multiple identity values, @@IDENTITY returns the last
>   identity value generated. If the statement fires one or more triggers
>   that perform inserts that generate identity values, calling @@IDENTITY
>   immediately after the statement returns the last identity value
>   generated by the triggers. If a trigger is fired after an insert
>   action on a table that has an identity column, and the trigger inserts
>   into another table that does not have an identity column, @@IDENTITY
>   returns the identity value of the first insert. The @@IDENTITY value
>   does not revert to a previous setting if the INSERT or SELECT INTO
>   statement or bulk copy fails, or if the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: Thanks. This SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Employee')+1 works

Comment: @KarlxSwanovski yes it may work when you're the only user. It will *absolutely not work* when you have concurrent usage.

Comment: @Astander can you please explain why you recommend looking into `IDENT_CURRENT`? As I outlined in my answer, this can produce very wrong results if there is more than one user.

Comment: No no no. I think I have been very misunderstood. I did not recomend this as an attemp to display the id to the user, BEFORE inserting it to the database. THAT IS COMPLETELY wrong. So @AaronBertrand, if you are listing, that ws not the suggestion. In fact, I would never recomend such a thing.