# Right Approach to Insert in Table then copy it to another table

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

In my application a user will insert a book. For example someBook will be insert with 3 copies. Table1.BookID = 1, Table1.Copy = 3, Then in another table those 3 books will have their primary key so it will be Table2.AccessionID = 1,2,3 Table2.BookID = 1, 1, 1.

This is what I current doing but a bad practice as what Aaron Bertrand said.

```
int BookTitlesID;
public void addBookTitle()
{
  int copy = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
  try
  {
    using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
    {
      myDatabaseConnection.Open();

      using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BookTitles(BookTitle, Copies) Values(@BookTitle,  @Copies)", myDatabaseConnection))
      {
        mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookTitle", BookTitletextBox.Text);
        mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Copies", copy);
        mySqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception Ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "Exception");
  }
}

public void addBook()
{
  int copy = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
  try
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < copy; x++)
    {
      using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
      {
        myDatabaseConnection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO book(BookTitleID) Values(@BookTitleID)", myDatabaseConnection))
        {
          mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookTitleID", BookTitlesID);
          mySqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception Ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "Exception");
  }
}

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
  {
    myDatabaseConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 BookTitleID + 1 FROM BookTitles ORDER BY BookTitleID DESC", myDatabaseConnection))
    {
      string x = mySqlCommand1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
      BookTitlesID = Convert.ToInt32(x);
    }
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  addBookTitle();
  addBook();
}
```

Comment: OMG. Dude, you should consider using an ORM. doing SQL in strings is an archaic concept. And please, for Christ's sake, remove all that code from the code behind and create a proper data access layer.

Comment: What is data access layer?

Comment: @KarlxSwanovski, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer

Comment: Is this a school project? If this is for your employer, I just wonder if it's fair to you (or to anyone) for you to be responsible for developing this application.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - a school project sir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplify. Most notably, [as discussed in your other, related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193865/query-to-get-the-next-identity), there is absolutely no safety in going out and seeing what the current `MAX` is, adding 1, and assuming that will be the next identity value generated. You can only rely on that number if you retrieve it *after* you have inserted, and the most reliable way to do that is to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` (or, for a multiple-row `INSERT`, an `OUTPUT` clause).

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertBook
  @BookTitle NVARCHAR(256),
  @Copies    INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @BookTitleID INT;

  INSERT dbo.BookTitles(BookTitle, Copies) SELECT @BookTitle, @Copies;

  SELECT @BookTitleID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

  INSERT dbo.Books(BookTitleID) SELECT @BookTitleID
  FROM (SELECT TOP (@Copies) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id]) AS y;
END
GO
```

Now you can really simplify your C# code (I'm not a C# guy, so whether this is the best approach or if it will even compile is beyond me, but hopefully you can sort that out on your own).

```
public void addBook()
{
  try
  {
    int Copies    = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    string BTitle = BookTitletextBox.Text
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection ...blah blah...)
    {
      conn.Open();

      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC dbo.InsertBook", conn))
      {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookTitle", BTitle);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Copies",    Copies);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception Ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "Exception");
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  addBook();
}
```

Comment: Still, keeping this data-related code in the code behind is a horrible practice, IMO. This should be part of either a service or a Data Access Object, or otherwise anywhere except in the UI.

Comment: @HighCore of course, we can completely redesign the OP's architecture if we want to, but I think for executing a single stored procedure - for a school project, no less - we can stop short of that.

Comment: Thank you so much Aaron Bertrand