# Display the ID of next record

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating an invoice and I want a textbox in it to display the id of the record that I am going to insert, I'ver heard about SCOPE_IDENTITY,@@IDENTITY and IDENT_CURRENT but they all seem to be displaying the id of the last record inserted and not the id of the new record.

I found this article but i ended up getting an error(https://www.bram.us/2008/07/30/mysql-get-next-auto_increment-value-fromfor-table/) this is the code im using now which gives the error:

```
try
{
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\Admin\supermarket1.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");
      SqlCommand invoiceno = new SqlCommand("SELECT InvoiceNo FROM Invoice", con);
      con.Open();
      SqlDataReader ie = invoiceno.ExecuteReader();
      while (ie.Read())
      {
           txtInvoice.Text = (ie[0].ToString());
      }
      con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an Identity column? And why you tagged with `mysql`? You don't even use none of those functions, what error you get?

Comment: `"which gives the error"` - *What* error?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do.  This code doesn't insert any record at all.  And in the description it sounds like you're trying to find the ID of a record which *hasn't been created yet*, in which case, well, there is no ID.  Because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Why show the ID to the user at all?  And why allow them to edit it?  The DB wont know the *next* Id until you insert a new record and a new Id is needed

Comment: You shouldn't take advice from a mysql blog post when you are using another database engine!

Comment: I don't think this is a best practice because of multiple reasons one of which is that you can not guarantee the next id if your system has more than one user, if there are many what happens if two users add a new invoice? The best practice for a case like this is to show the generated number after inserting the row in the database.

Comment: Why should it be necessary to see the "next ID"? Especially, what if two users are online at the same time: Both will see an number, say, 1234. Both are thinking they 'have' the number 1234 ... but only one will win

So this is an absolute bad idea.

What exactly do you want to get? Please Explain your task more detailed.

Comment: To get the last inserted autovalue value in your table, you can use the 'OUTPUT INSERTED <yourfieldnamehere>' clause of SQL Server (and use the return value of ExecuteScalar for getting the value)

Comment: It's not possible to know what the NEXT number is until you have used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the ID of the current record because that's what you are asking the database for.

`SELECT InvoiceNo FROM Invoice` Is a query which is requesting all the existing invoices. You are then iterating over every single invoice number and updating your `txtInvoice.Text` until you reach the last invoice that was created.

There might be a solution to this but I don't feel that it's a good idea, you can't reliably get the `Next InvoiceNo`.

What happens if 2 users are using this software at the same time? They both see the same `Next InvoiceNo`, one person will actually end up getting a different `InvoiceNo` when they go to save.

Alternatively you could reserve an `InvoiceNo` by creating a blank row but then what happens if someone decides not to save data? You would need to handle these blank records properly, for example what if someone cancels the order, how do you ensure that the record is disposed of? what about if you have reporting of some sort, now your queries need to exclude blank records. This is additional overhead.

It might be worth revisiting the requirement, does the invoice really need a `InvoiceNo` before it is created?

Comment: Thanks, yea it was a bad idea to start with :/

Answer (score 1):

When the new invoice page is requested, immediately insert a new blank record in the Invoice table, and use `Scope_Identity()` to get the ID of the new Invoice.

Then you can display the ID of the new invoice on the page, and `UPDATE` that invoice with the information the user enters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get that, and if it is possible by a SQL method I don't know, I can't trust this ID specially in multi instance applications such as web applications or mobile apps, as for example the moment you got the ID may be another record inserted and this ID number you got become not the next one value.

So If this is a must requirement I would recommend disable auto identity increment in the DB and make it managed by your application, like that you will have more control on Identities and can know exactly the current one and next easily.

And if this is a single instance app, you can just add 1 to the current record Identity.

and I found someone asked something the same on SO [Query to get the next identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193865/query-to-get-the-next-identity)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the ID of the invoice prior to it's creation? I can't think to a serious reason.

The solution proposed by Tab Alleman will work but it might cause problems: What if the user changes his mind and cancels the operation? Of course you can delete the temporary record but the `id` was already used. So what's the problem? In my country there is a legal requirement which states that **consecutive** registration numbers should be allocated for documents (...), so no gaps are allowed. Also the registration number **must** be printed on the document.
Just do the job in multiple steps:

- Insert the record in the database
- Query the id of the newly created record
- Use the obtained id to print your invoice